# How to authenticate to bitbucket cloud APIs and then use them post authentication?

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

Bitbucket cloud APIs have decent documentation, but I could not find a comprehensive exampl showing how to make authenticated calls to those APIs.

My requirement is very simple.  As a bitbucket cloud admin for a given workspace, I would like to get a list of all the repos the workspace has.

I would like to be able to do this from my python backend (a simple script & nothing else). There is no user interaction involved in this case.  Now having gone through the documentation & a bunch of online resources, it appears that there are a few ways to get authentication tokens, which is (obviously) the first step to be able to call any other APIs.

Here are a few things I'm struggling with & would really appreciate any inputs around the same : (PS: pointing me to the right resources would also be great help. Don't *necessarily* need direct spoon fed answers :) )

1. What's the difference between the different tokens? On Bitbucket cloud I can see App Tokens & Oauth Consumers. Which one is the one to be used in my case above? And with each, what should be the respective header value?
2. What's the endpoint to which the call needs to be made? For example to get a list of the all repos in the given workspace, for which I am an admin, would it be https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<my_workspace_name_here> or would it be https://bitbucket.org/<my_workspace_name_here>/2.0/repositories/ or would it be something else?
3. There is this *official* python lib from Atlassian https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html which does seem to talk about how to get the authentication done for Bitbucket cloud using the app password, something like using the below:

   ```
   bitbucket_app_pw= Cloud(
   url='https://api.bitbucket.org/',
   username=bitbucket_username,
   password=bitbucket_app_password,
   cloud=True)
   ```

and then the corresponding API call to list the repos seems to be

```
bitbucket.project_list()
```

but the **bitbucket** Cloud object (in this case **bitbucket_app_pw**), obtained from the former snippet above, does not seem to have the **project_list** method at all. Is the `url` keyword argument to the `Cloud()` supposed to be exactly that, or is that just a sample & actually supposed to be replaced with something like `https://api.bitbucket.org/<my_workspace_name_here>`
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you clarify, is your question about how to use the API or is it about how to use the `atlassian-python-api` library with Bitbucket? FWIW that library is not official, it's not developed or maintained by Atlassian. It's unclear to me whether you need help using this lib, or with the API itself.

Comment: I primarily need help with the Bitbucket APIs itself. The python api is a secondary requirement. Even if I don't get any help around that, it is fine. I can manage without it. @daveruinseverything

Comment: @qre0ct did you able to solve the issue. I'm also struggling with the same thing as mentioned above.